# How to fix Unbound Local Error in my code in Python?

Tags: python

Can you help me fix this cod?
After I run it like after 30 sec, it says "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'command' referenced before assignment" Can you help me fix it? I tried many tutorials on how to fix this error but I can't.

```
import speech_recognition as sr
import pyttsx3
import pywhatkit
import datetime
import pyjokes

listener = sr.Recognizer()
engine = pyttsx3.init()
voices = engine.getProperty('voices')
engine.setProperty('voice', voices[1].id)


def talk(text):
    engine.say(text)
    engine.runAndWait()


def take_command():
    try:
        with sr.Microphone() as source:
            print('listening...')
            voice = listener.listen(source)
            command = listener.recognize_google(voice)
            command = command.lower()
            if 'idiot' in command:
                command = command.replace('idiot', '')
                print(command)
    except:
        pass

    return command

def run_idiot():
    command = take_command()
    print(command)
    if 'play' in command:
        song = command.replace('play', '')
        talk('playing ' + song)
        pywhatkit.playonyt(song)
    elif 'time' in command:
        time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%I:%M %p')
        print(time)
        talk(time)
    
    else:
        talk('Please say the command again.')


while True:
    run_idiot()
```

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't have a definition of `command` if an exception occurs, thus returning it would cause the Unbounded Local Error. So you need to declare it first:

```
def take_command():
    # declare 'command' variable outside try-except
    command = ""
    try:
        with sr.Microphone() as source:
            print('listening...')
            voice = listener.listen(source)
            command = listener.recognize_google(voice)
            command = command.lower()
            if 'idiot' in command:
                command = command.replace('idiot', '')
                print(command)
    except:
        pass

    return command
```